# Lambda logic - multiple checks

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm struggling to get my head around the logic of any vs all and multiple selects
I have a model thats mapped from an Xelement and i want to check if multiple attributes have a value (thats an indicator of a valid request) but my check below keeps returning false (even though i know they have values)

```
 if(!electronicObject.MetaData.All(x=> x.Name.ToLower() == "parcel id" || 
                                                x.Name.ToLower() == "parcel type" ||                                                           x.Name.ToLower() == "street name" ||
                                                      x.Name.ToLower() == "street designation" ||
                                                      x.Name.ToLower() == "parcel status"))
```

Comment: `All` means every item in the list must pass the conditions. Even if one item does not, then it will return false. `Any` means even if one item passes the condition, return true. I think you want `where` because it will return all items that pass the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are checking if ALL elements in the metadata are named "parcel id", "parcel type", "street name" ,"street address" or "parcel status". So if your metadata has those 5 elements and 1 more, called, for example, "some stuff", your check will fail.

Probably what you want to achieve is to check that you have any of those attributes available in the collection:

```
if(electronicObject.MetaData.Any(x=> x.Name.ToLower() == "parcel id" || 
                                      x.Name.ToLower() == "parcel type" ||
                                      x.Name.ToLower() == "street name" ||
                                      x.Name.ToLower() == "street designation" ||
                                      x.Name.ToLower() == "parcel status"))
{
  //your object is probably correct, as it has at least one correct metadata element.
}
```

This condition will return true even for collections that are not full: "foo", "bar", "street address" is still correct. I dont know if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Like @CodingYoshi says, it seems like you might prefer `Any` instead of `All`.

As such, you could state it like this:

```
var categories = new[]{
    "parcel id", 
    "parcel type", 
    "street name", 
    "street designation", 
    "parcel status"
};
var condition = electronicObject.MetaData
                                .Any(x => categories.Contains(x.Name.ToLower()));
if(!condition)
{
    //blah
}
```